# 2D plot of x,y,z points in Python without Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, coordinates

I have a set of 3d points (I generate the positions of planets and moons in a stellar system from Keplers equations) I have the coordinates of all points as x,y,z, where the central star is 0,0,0. The code to produce the points works perfectly.

However, at the moment I plot a visualisation of this system from above - so I just ignore the z component for the purposes of visualisation and plot the x and y to the canvas as-is. This works as intended.

How would I generate x and y coordinates for plotting to the canvas that take into account the z coordinate, so that I can plot a view from another angle apart from directly above?

The only library I can use apart from the standard one would be numpy. I cannot use Matplotlib.

*edit* thanks to the comments I can now clarify with some psudocode.

Assume I have a bunch of points that have an xyz position.

What I currently do:

canvas.plot(point.x)

canvas.plot(point.y)

ignoring point z - so that it is as if all z's are 0 and it is viewed from 'above'

So that I can use my current plotting code - which takes into account scale and offsets to do with the canvas, I need new x and y coordinates that are as if the view is from another angle other than 'above'.

It seems from the helpful comments what I have to do is rotate the whole coordinate system so that it has a new z axis that is a result of a rotation of the whole system about the x and y axis.

Something like the following psudocode would do.

```
def rotate_about_axis(x_rotation_degrees, y_rotation_degrees, point.x, point.y, point.z):
    new_plot_x = canvas_point_to_plot after magic code to rotate coordinates x_rotation_degrees about x axis
    new_plot_y = canvas_point_to_plot after magic code to rotate coordinates y_rotation_degrees about y axis

return new_plot_x, new_plot_y
```

Then I could apply this to all the points I plot.

How would I do this in python?

Comment: How do you currently plot your visualization?

Comment: There are a few ways. The simplest is I just plot the x and y coordinates to a html canvas. I have the z but I don't use it.

Comment: so you only have access to numpy? Numpy is not a plotting library, how would reckon to plot anything without a graphical back-end? There are other libraries; vispy, plotly, ggplot [...]. Other than a terminal output I am not sure what this post wants.

Comment: I can, and do plot to an html canvas. I could scale apropriately and plot ascii to a text file. Lots of ways are available. That isn't my problem. I just don't know how to produce x and y from the x, y and z, in python. Pretty sure there is a way with numpy. Matplotlib would just do it, but there we go...

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are doing. If you have a 2d canvas and want to account for the z coordinate you have to do some affine transformation to get the in relative perspective. which is possible with numpy only.

Comment: @deMangler: Two more question (I'm trying to figure out how much of the math needs to be explicitly worked out): 1) do you only have numpy and python, or do you have access to scipy as well, and possibly other libraries?; 2) do you care how the viewing angle is specified?

Comment: I don't care how the viewing angle is specified - I think numpy is sufficient as I work out the xyz coordinates from keplerian elements using that. The only import Ihave realted to this is from numpy import pi, abs, sqrt, cos, sin, arctan, tan. To be honest I am fairly sure it is not that difficult but it is one of those things that I cannot wrap my head around.

Comment: The basic idea here is to rotate the coordinate system to one where the z-axis is along the view angle that you want, and then plot `x'` and `y'` like you currently do. That is, find a rotation matrix `R`, and multiply all your `(x, y, z)` points by that. Finding `R` is the only involved step, but there are numpy examples available, or you could build `R` from multiple 2D rotations (from `R0 = [cos sin 0; -sin cos 0, 0 0 1]`, or you could use scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation, etc.

Comment: Thank you tom10. I will post an answer if I can come up with anything based on that.

Comment: What is interesting is that now that I know how to phrase the question better - there are  a lot of examples in stack-exchange, but only those that would make sense to someone who already understands the answer.... example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1525573/3d-coordinates-rotation-new-direction-for-z-axis

Comment: Does this have anything to do with 3D projection onto 2D? That might be a good place to start, although I can't imagine its trivial to implement (or understand)

Comment: @dantechguy: Yes, this is just a way to make a projection from 3D onto a 2D plane: Plotting (x,y) of 3D (x,y,z) points is a projection onto the x-y plane along the z-axis. And the plotting (x',y') of (x',y',z') in a rotated basis is projecting onto the rotated x'-y' plane. Coordinate transformations are a common operation, so it's a useful language to describe it in and find the math for, but one can also just think of projecting onto an arbitrary plane without thinking of it as part of a coordinate system, and the math and results are the same.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comments - I found this helpful in my search for an answer  https://github.com/duolu/pyrotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with an answer, I hope it helps someone.

```
import numpy, math

def rotate_about_axis(x_rotation_degrees, y_rotation_degrees, point_x, point_y, point_z):

    xrads = math.radians(x_rotation_degrees)
    yrads = math.radians(y_rotation_degrees)
    rotation = [xrads, yrads, 0]
    rotation_angle = numpy.linalg.norm(rotation)
    norm_rotation = rotation / numpy.linalg.norm(rotation)
    base_points = [point_x, point_y, point_z]
    points = numpy.dot(base_points, norm_rotation) * norm_rotation
    points_difference = base_points - points
    points_transform = numpy.cross(norm_rotation, base_points)
    rotated_points = points + points_difference * numpy.cos(rotation_angle) + points_transform * numpy.sin(rotation_angle)

    rotated_point_x = rotated_points[0]
    rotated_point_y = rotated_points[1]

    return(rotated_point_x, rotated_point_y)
```